# mongodb won't start on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb for the first time on Ubuntu 16.10. I've installed it successfully but when I try to run it I got this error. When I type `mongo` on my terminal

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-03-21T22:29:13.268+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-03-21T22:29:13.268+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-03-21T22:29:13.268+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-03-21T22:29:14.010+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-03-21T22:29:14.010+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-03-21T22:29:14.010+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-03-21T22:29:14.010+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-03-21T22:29:14.010+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-03-21T22:29:14.010+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2017-03-21T22:29:14.011+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2017-03-21T22:29:14.011+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

When I type `mongod` I got this message instead

```
2017-03-21T22:46:31.103+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13038 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=michael-Satellite-L740
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.2
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-03-21T22:46:31.104+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I'm very new to linux and `mongodb` so any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Is there a `data/db` folder in root `/`?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599119/mongodb-not-working-error-dbpath-data-db-does-not-exist)

Comment: sorry for the late reply @ShreyashSSarnayak yes db folder is there on data folder there is only 1 file on it (mongo.lock)

Comment: @Jos it's not working :( still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

Starting mongodb on latest version of ubuntu is a bit different.

The correct code to start mongodb is

`sudo service mongodb start`

To confirm that mongodb is running run

`sudo service mongodb status`

Other commands include

`sudo service mongodb stop` 
 `sudo service mongodb restart`